# Performance of Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate Query is very slow

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am working on a project that requires JDBC Calls to an Oracle Database. I have set up UCP pooling to work with SpringJDBC. I have a fairly simple query that I am executing like the following...

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (:ids)`

my java code to set this query up looks like the following...

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource);
Map<String,Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
paramMap.put("ids", Arrays.asList(idArray));

List<Result> results = template.query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (:ids)",
    paramMap, new ResultRowMapper());
```

This all performs fine as long as there is only 1 id in the array. When I add a 2nd ID the query takes nearly 5 minutes to run. If I take the exact query and execute it in SQLDeveloper, it takes .093 seconds.

Something must be going terribly wrong with my code or configuration... Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

I stripped out the usage of the Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and went with just straight Jdbc and everything seems to perform great. What is it that NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is doing differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the difference between my straight jdbc solution and my spring-jdbc solution in this situation... It appears that as @Annjawn below explained, it is a bind variable issue not a spring-jdbc issue. My spring-jdbc issue was trying to bind a variable to an index (that doesn't exist) thus doing a table scan...

My straight JDBC solution ends up just doing a string replacement and executing as is thus no table scan...

The below link explains the difference.

http://bytes.com/topic/oracle/answers/65559-jdbc-oracle-beware-bind-variables

Comment: Its not Spring-jdbc vs jdbc, its any bind variable issue. doesn't matter whether its spring-jdbc or plain jdbc, if there are bind variable in a java program using jdbc, what ever the article says about cost based optimizer, is true. I would think that its more how your code is working with the spring-jdbc. Why not try and see the results using `template.queryForList()` instead of `template.query()`.